# How to install gevent in a Python virtualenv?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, virtualenv

I'm trying to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) on my Ubuntu 14.04 server, but I can't seem to install `gevent`. I first activate virtualenv, afther which I install `gevent` using pip:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)immoh@vgmt:~/immod$ sudo pip install gevent
The directory '/home/immoh/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/immoh/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gevent in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): greenlet>=0.4.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from gevent)
```

After this I try to use it from the python command line:

```
(venv)immoh@vgmt:~/immod$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gevent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gevent
>>>
```

That didn't seem to work, so I tried installing it using the `sudo's -H flag` as suggested by the message above, but after that again, I can't import `gevent`:

```
(venv)immoh@vgmt:~/immod$ sudo -H pip install gevent
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gevent in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): greenlet>=0.4.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from gevent)
(venv)immoh@vgmt:~/immoh$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gevent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gevent
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here and how I can solve this? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the problem is that you are using `sudo` when you should not be. Once you're working in a virtualenv, just run `pip` without `sudo` and you should have none of these issues.

By the way, I recommend creating a new virtualenv in which to try this, to avoid any problems created by your previous attempts.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't realise this, but it sounds very logical. Placing `sudo` before every install has just become such a habit. Thanks!